# problem with require_once

Tags: php

I have a file structure like this

```
config 
  config.php
library
  data.php
folder
  file1.php
libs.inc.php
test1.php
```

In config file iam  including
require_once('libs.inc.php'); and 
require_once('./library/data.php');
In file1.php i am including config file using 'require_once('../config/config.php');'
But it showing error in  require_once('libs.inc.php'); and 
require_once('./library/data.php');
How i can solve this problem Thanks in advance..

Comment: why do you have inconsistent relative paths? i see `./`, `../`, and one that relies on the include_path!

Answer (score 2):

```
require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/../library/data.php');
require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/../libs.inc.php');
```

or

```
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/library/data.php');
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/libs.inc.php');
```

Comment: Instead of `dirname(__FILE__)` you can use the shorter magic constant [`__DIR__`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php).

Answer (score 0):

In config.php:

```
require_once('../library/data.php');
require_once('../libs.inc.php');
```

Comment: in test1.php you would `require_once('config/config.php');`  but Scott's answer applies to _within_ your `config.php` file

Comment: if i do like that i am getting  error in test1.php.
Warning: require_once(../libs.inc.php) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/bbank/RealHelpAppNew/config/config.php  on line 10.

In file1.php there is no error